# need to parse a json object response in String and put in list

Tags: android, json, parsing

i get a server response in the form of a json object. the result is the following:

```
{"status":0,"values":[{"valueid":110,"listid":2,"value":"Roba da Makers"},{"valueid":120,"listid":2,"value":"PC Notebook"}]
```

I would like to get the the string values of `value` and put them in a list.

For example in this case i would like to just get "Roba da Makers" and "PC Notebook" and put them in a `List<String>`

Comment: have you made an attempt? If so, post it. If not, make an attempt and then post it.

Comment: While making an attempt. Look into using the Gson library maybe.

Comment: please share code which you have tried to parse given JSON String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by converting it to a JSONObject.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("your string");
if( obj.has("values") )
{
  JSONArray valueArray = obj.getJSONArray("values");
  for( int i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++ )
  {
     JSONObject valueObj = valueArray.get(i);
     if( valueObj.has("value") )
     {
        String value = valueObj.getString("value");
        //Do whatever you want with your string values.
     }
  }
}
```